# Hard and soft links (junctions) under Windows

Tags: files, microsoft-windows, symbolic-links

Let us assume to run the following commands creating links in the Windows prompt (terminal):

```
> mkdir fooDir
> echo hello> fooDir\foo
> mklink /d fooDirSym fooDir
> mklink /j fooDirJunc fooDir
> mklink /h fooDir\fooHard fooDir\foo
> cd fooDir
> mklink fooSym foo
```

Moving to Emacs, this works as expected:

```
(file-truename "path/to/fooDir/fooSym")
    => "path/to/fooDir/foo"
(file-nlinks "path/to/fooDir/foo")
    => 2 (#o2, #x2, ?\C-b)
 ;; The second name should be fooDir/fooHard
(file-truename "c:/p/fooDirSym")
    => "path/to/fooDir"
```

Now:

```
(file-truename "path/to/fooDirJunc")
    => "path/to/fooDirJunc"
(file-nlinks "path/to/fooDir/")
    => 1 (#o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
```

A Windows junction is not counted as a hard link (and in fact it is a soft link) and it is not a symlink.

The questions now are:

How do we identify the pathnames (not only the number) of hard links to foo?
How do we identify the presence and the path of  junctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on [Microsoft junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) by Mark Russinovich.

```
(defun get-target (dir)
  "If DIR is a junction, return its target, else return DIR.
The 'junction' util is assumed to be in your path."  
  (setq dir (expand-file-name (substitute-in-file-name dir)))
  (let* (out (bin "junction.exe"))    
    (unless (executable-find bin) (error (concat "Unable to find the tool " bin)))
    (setq out (car (last (split-string
              (shell-command-to-string
               (concat "junction "
                   (shell-quote-argument
                    (replace-regexp-in-string
                     "/" "\\\\"
                     (replace-regexp-in-string "/$" "" dir)))))
              "\n" t))))
    (if (string-match "^ +Substitute Name: " out)
    (expand-file-name (replace-match "" nil nil out)) dir)))
```